# How to remove empty or None fields in deeply nested dictionary of unknown depth?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary of deeply nested dictionaries and I am trying to remove all k-v pairs that are None or "". The below dictionary `d` is an example of the input.

```
d = { 
  "1": {
    "1_1": 'a real value',
    "1_2": ""
    },
   "2": None,
   "3": {
     "3_1": {
       "3_2": None
     }
   }
}
```

Normally, to remove empty fields in a dictionary, the command `{k:v for k,v in d.items() if v}` does the job. But in this case, I want to remove all the nested dictionaries whose values are empty or null, and I can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

After `d` passes through this transformation, all the empty dictionaries whose values are empty should be gone. It should look like this:

```
{ 
  "1": {
    "1_1": 'a real value',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'1': {'1_1': 'a real value', '1_2': ''}, '2': None, '3': {'3_1': {'3_2': None}}}
def get_d(d):
  return {a:c for a, b in d.items() if (c:=(b if not isinstance(b, dict) else get_d(b)))}

print(get_d(d))
```

Output:

```
{'1': {'1_1': 'a real value'}}
```

Note: this solution uses Python's assignment expressions (`:=`) available in versions >= 3.8. For a solution that does not use this paradigm, please see @Anonymous's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function to *recursively* remove empty dictionaries. For example:

```
def return_non_empty(my_dict):
    temp_dict = {}
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if v:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                 return_dict = return_non_empty(v)
                 if return_dict:
                     temp_dict[k] = return_dict
            else:
                temp_dict[k] = v
    return temp_dict
```

---

For example, if `d` is:

```
d = { 
  "1": {
    "1_1": 'a real value',
    "1_2": ""
    },
   "2": None,
   "3": {
     "3_1": {
       "3_2": None
     }
   }
}
```

then my custom function `return_non_empty` will return:

```
>>> return_non_empty(d)
{'1': {'1_1': 'a real value'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This python function recursively removes dictionary keys whose values are empty, None, False, or 0.

```
def remove_empty_keys(dictionary):
    if isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        for key, value in dictionary.copy().items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                remove_empty_keys(value)
            if not value:
                del(dictionary[key])
```

Similar to [@Ajax1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2063361/moinuddin-quadri)'s answer but this function acts directly on target dictionary rather than outputting a new one.

Comment: How would you approach this  if you only want to remove None and empty values but NOT not 0 or false?

Comment: @PloniStacker I might change the last line to `if type(value) != bool and type(value) != int: del(dictionary[key])`